# query to convert mongodb array to key value pair

Tags: mongodb

i need to create a mongodb query to convert an array into key-value

my document is like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c8718b9b5fe262104408374"),
    "axis" : "x",
    "message_time" : ISODate("2019-03-11T08:04:41.000Z"),
    "x_axis" : [ 
        0.9766, 
        1.9531, 
        2.9297, 
        3.9063, 
        4.8828, 
        5.8594, 
        6.8359, 
        7.8125, 
        8.7891,
    ],
    "etl_date_time" : ISODate("2019-03-12T02:26:01.510Z")
}
```

i want to convert it to

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c8718b9b5fe262104408374"),
    "axis" : "x",
    "message_time" : ISODate("2019-03-11T08:04:41.000Z"),
    "x_axis" : 8.7891,
    "etl_date_time" : ISODate("2019-03-12T02:26:01.510Z")
}
```

can anyone help me with the query?

Comment: Whats the logic behind convertion process from an array to key-value pair?

Comment: So, you want the last element (8.7891) of the `x_axis` array assigned to the same field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggreggation framework to achieve this.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      x_axis: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $slice: [
              "$x_axis",
              -1
            ]
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If you need to perform an update on your collection, you can add an [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) stage

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zq-ei-t-6CE)

Comment: what to do if i want to update same document with this result

Comment: add an $out stage at the end of this aggregation, targeting the same collection. The use of $addField stage with same key (x_axis)  / will keep other fields unchanged. And the documents will be replaced based on their _id field.